# Microsoft Dynamics SOAP: How to specify DateTime Filter in XML?

Tags: xml, soap, microsoft-dynamics

We have a Microsoft Dynamics (Navision) 2016 running and use the Soap-API.

The Soap-Request-Header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:mac="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/mytable">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mac:ReadMultiple>
        <mac:filter>
            <mac:Field>Time</mac:Field>
            <mac:Criteria>2019*</mac:Criteria>
        </mac:filter>
      </mac:ReadMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response to this request gives an error:

```
<faultcode xmlns:a="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/error">
    a:Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Types.Exceptions.NavFilterException</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
    The filter "2019*" is not valid for the Time field on the mytable table. 
    The value "2019*" can't be evaluated into type DateTime.
</faultstring>
```

My questions is: How to make a filter just giving records from 2019 and later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. Try changing

```
<mac:Field>Time</mac:Field>
   <mac:Criteria>2019*</mac:Criteria>
```

to:

```
<mac:Field>Date</mac:Field>
    <mac:Criteria>&gt;=01012019</mac:Criteria>
```

and see if works.

Comment: Seems to work, indeed! Is "01012019" defined as <dd><mm><yyyy> or <mm><dd><yyyy>? My tests do no give clear results.

Comment: Is there a documentation available on the web about the filter specs?

Comment: @WeSee - not that much; I just remembered from something I did a while ago. It may even have originated from an SO question, but I don't remember...